# Downloading OEM USB drivers for samsung tablet model number GT-P51110

Tags: android, android-studio

I have a samsung tablet model number GT-P5110 and i need to download the OEM USB drivers as i can't test out my apps that i have created on android studio, can someone please provide me a link of where i should download these drivers. Your help and comments will be much appriciated.

Comment: Which platform are you developing from, windows, Linux or mac OS?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Which platform are you developing from, windows, Linux or mac OS? Samsung drivers are usually generic, not for a specific model. [Samsung Kies](http://www.samsung.com/us/smart-switch/) normally works well on windows and Mac. On Linux,  you don't need drivers. I had issues with my Gt-5100 playing nicely with USB 3 and USB2 on both windows and Linux.  My SM-P901 played well on USB3 and USB2 on windows, but, it only played nice with USB2 on Linux.  Meaning,  playing with adb.

Answer (score 0):

There are two drivers when your connect samsung tablet to computer. One is USB driver, and one is tablet driver. You can try to download a drivers download software from Cnet and helps you scan your computer. It will recommend you the right driver.